# How to get differencies between two elements in JSON files

Tags: python, json

I have these two JSON files with the same structure:

```
a_communities = {"communities": [{"group": "D06@domain.com", "members": ["member1", "member2"]}, {"group": "D07@domain.com", "members": ["member3"]}]}
b_communities = {"communities": [{"group": "D06@domain.com", "members": ["member1", "member2", "members3"]}, {"group": "D07@domain.com", "members": ["member4"]}]}
```

I want to get difference between the same group in the two files: get members who are/are not in the same group in the two files

I have tried to get them wit this function:

```
def get_g_members_from_value(group, value):
    for g_community in g_communities['communities']:
        if g_community['group'] == str(group): #the same group then:
            print "***"+str(reduce(lambda v1,v2: v1 or v2, list(set(g_community['members']).difference(value))))
            if [i for i, j in zip(g_community['members'] , value) if i != j] != []:
                print "members are not equal for group :"+str(group)
                print "-- g members :"+str(g_community['members'])
                print "-- c members :"+str(value)
                print "-- diff :"+ str([i for i, j in zip(g_community['members'] , value) if i != j])

for c_community in c_communities['communities']:
    get_g_members_from_value(c_community['group'], c_community['members'])
```

I have printed more results to see the differences but it cant get me the diff, what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Assuming that each `group` has a unique name, it might be easier to convert to a dictionary of the form `{group: set(members)}` for each community, then just use `set.difference` to get the changes between communities.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: you want to say two sets: `{group: set(members_a_communities)}, {same_group: set(members_b_communities}` how to get differencies then ?

Comment: Using the [`difference` instance method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) (or [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference)) for the same key (i.e. same group) between the two dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand my comments into code, I would first convert the structures you currently have into dictionaries in the form `{'group_name': set(group_members)}` for each community:

```
>>> a_members = {d['group']: set(d['members']) for d in a_communities['communities']}
>>> b_members = {d['group']: set(d['members']) for d in b_communities['communities']}
>>> a_members
{'D06@domain.com': set(['member1', 'member2']), 'D07@domain.com': set(['member3'])}
>>> b_members
{'D06@domain.com': set(['members3', 'member1', 'member2']), 'D07@domain.com': set(['member4'])}
```

Then use [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference)

```
>>> for key in a_members:
    print key, a_members[key].symmetric_difference(b_members[key])


D06@domain.com set(['members3'])
D07@domain.com set(['member4', 'member3'])
```

and [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> for key in a_members:
    print key, a_members[key].intersection(b_members[key])


D06@domain.com set(['member1', 'member2'])
D07@domain.com set([])
```

To get the differences and similiarities in membership between the two communities. This all assumes that:

1. Each `group` has a unique name; and
2. The `members` list contains hashable objects.